# Create array type of push in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to create this structure in firebase:

```
inMinistries
--uidOfGroup1
----0: uidOfGroup1Member
----1: uidOfGroup1Member
----2: uidOfGroup1Member
--uidOfGroup2
----0: uidOfGroup2Member
----1: uidOfGroup2Member
```

In the above example inMinistries is the first node, then we have uidofGroup1 which would be a uid of a Group then I want child nodes to appear like uidOfGroup1Member.  There are several so I can't say exactly how many I need.

Here is my attempt to create the above:

```
class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    this.auth = app.auth();
    this.db = app.database();
    this.storage = app.storage();
  }
```

This is how I set the uidOfGroups

```
this.db.ref(`inMinistries/${uidOfGroup}`).set('members')
```

I pass a uid value I receive from another call.  I set 'members' so that I could replace it with a group of members later.

I then try to create uidOfGroup1Members, uidOfGroup2Members.  I get stuck on this part.  If I do a set like so:

```
this.db.ref(`/inMinistries/${uidOfGroup}}`).set(memberId);
```

I can only pass the memberId once, meaning I'd need to have the full list of uidOfGroupMembers which I don't have all at once.  I'd like to be able to push it like I would in an array.  But if I do push:

```
this.db.ref(`/inMinistries/${uidOfGroup}}`).push(memberId);
```

then it adds an extra uid to the value before like so:
[image]

Note the above is actually using the uids.  How can I achieve the original desired result I placed on top?

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the entire set of code that composes this database entry, that isn't working the way you expect? You're leaving a lot unknown behind the variable `memberId`.  We should be able to duplicate what you're seeing using the code you provide.

Comment: I added it, I hope it helps, I have all this in some other methods but I think this will convey what I'm doing.  @DougStevenson

Comment: Your problem comes form the fact that the [`push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=2#push) methods creates a **child** location with an auto generated unique key. You should use the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=2#set) method which will write data at the location itself. Note, in addition, that it seems that you pass an array with one element to the `push()` method, since you get `-0: "-Lwk98aSO7iFTu0qNFJD"`. You may just pass the `-Lwk98aSO7iFTu0qNFJD` string.

Comment: But if I use set then the data will always override the last one.  That is why I was attempting to use push.  @RenaudTarnec

Comment: You need to give more info in order for us to help you (this is why your question why closed BTW). For the moment there is only **one** value under the `LxnUH8J0gbATDKycZYN` node, so it seems using `set()` should not be a problem (since you can only overwrite it!). If your problem is wider, please ask a new question with all the details.

Comment: I updated the question I hope this will help to clarify what I'm asking @RenaudTarnec

Comment: Is there a specific reason for storing the uidOfGroupMember with a specific "index" (i.e. 0, 1, 2)? You could very well store them as, for example, `uidOfGroup1Member: uidOfGroup1Member`or `uidOfGroup1Member: true`, it would make your problem much easier, since you will be able to use `set()`.

Comment: No I can do like you are saying but one of the problems with using set() is that I need to keep the previous data there from before.  That is why I wanted it to be like an array push type @RenaudTarnec

Comment: "I need to keep the previous data there from before" -> That I understand. Could you please answer to this question: "Is there a specific reason for storing the uidOfGroupMember with a specific "index" (i.e. 0, 1, 2)?" If no, I can propose you a solution that will fulfill your requirements.

Comment: No specific reason to save it with "index" I don't even need an index.  @RenaudTarnec

Comment: Ok, give me 10 minutes!

Comment: THANK YOU @RenaudTarnec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no constraint on how you save the different `uidsOfGroupMember` under a specific `uidOfGroup` (in particular no need for using a specific "index" (i.e. 0, 1, 2)), you could use the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=2#set) method as follows:

```
  var uidOfGroup = 'uidOfGroup1';

  var uidOfGroup1Member = 'uidOfGroup1Member';  //Of course, here you can assign the value you want, e.g. -Lwk98a...
  this.db.ref(`/inMinistries/${uidOfGroup}/${uidOfGroup1Member}`).set(
    uidOfGroup1Member
  );


  var uidOfGroup2Member = 'uidOfGroup2Member';
  this.db.ref(`/inMinistries/${uidOfGroup}/${uidOfGroup2Member}`).set(
    uidOfGroup2Member
  );
```

---

One difference between the `push()` and the `set()` methods is that `push()` creates a **child** location with an auto generated unique key, which is the cause of your problem.

Comment: If I want to keep previous data in a UidOfGroup in example I run a set today and tomorrow I need to set new data would I ref the data, copy it and then rerun a set? @Renaud Tamec

Comment: No, this is what the example shows: we first write `uidOfGroup1Member` and then, after, we write `uidOfGroup2Member`. The two values (i.e. the two nodes) are present under `UidOfGroup` at the end.